# Getting a label's value using select's name tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a system that can output 0 or more select boxes and I need to add some Javascript/JQuery validation. I am new to writing JQuery and I am stuck getting the content of the text label for the error message: Here is an example of my select boxes form:

```
<div id="prodOptions" class="sale">
   <p class="elevenText floatLeft">Product options</p>
    <div class="floatLeft"><label for="colour">Select Colour</label>
    <select name="colour">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="floatLeft">
    <label for="size">Select Size</label>
    <select name="size">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
        <option value="small">Small</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="floatLeft">
    <label for="flavour">Select Flavour</label>
    <select name="flavour">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
        <option value="cherry">Cherry</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript function which is called on form submission (the alerts are for testing):

```
function validateOptions()
{

    selectList = $('select').get();
    message = "";

    for(i=0; i<selectList.length; ++i)
    {

            //alert(selectList[i].name);
            selector = "for[=\""+selectList[i].name+"\"]";
            alert(selector);
            alert($(selector.value));
            message += ($(selectList[i]).prop('selected', true).val() == "") ? "Please enter a value for \r\n" : "";

    }

    alert(message); 

}
```

Comment: Incidentally, you need to add id attributes to your form variables if you want labels to find them. Name attributes are not searched for, since they don't have to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attribute syntax is incorrect. Your selector should be

```
var selector = "label[for='" + selectList[i].name + "']";
```

From there, you should fetch the label's `.html()`, rather than `.val()`

Also, labels should reference element ID's, rather than names. It is also not very clear how you want your message to be formatted. You should be able to do something like this:

```
function validateOptions()
{

    var message = '';

    $('select').each(function() {
       if($(this).val() == '') {
          var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
          message += 'Please select a value for: ' + label.html() + '\n';
       }
    });

    alert(message);
}
```

You could also format your error message like so:

```
function validateOptions()
{
    var emptyFields = [];
    $('select').each(function() {
       if($(this).val() == '') {
          var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
          emptyFields.push(label.html());
       }
    });

    if(emptyFields.length > 0) {
       alert('Please select a value for:\n' + emptyFields.join('\n'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function validateOptions() {
                message = "";

                $('select').each(function (i) {
                    message += ($(this).prop('selected', true).val() == "") ? "Please enter a value for" + $(this).prev().html() + " \r\n" : "";
                });

                alert(message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ var allSelect = $('select');

 $.each(allSelect,function(k,v){

    var thIs = $(this);
    var name = thIs.attr('name');

    if(name == 'colour')
    {
       // Do what you want to do with colour select here eg:-
       alert(thIs.prev('label').text());
       } else if(name == 'size'){
       alert(thIs.prev('label').text());
       } else if(name == 'flavour'){
       alert(thIs.prev('label').text());
       }
   return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Why do you keep capitalizing `this` the way you do?

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that it was a variable, sorry. Yeah, I agree that you shouldn't try to overwrite `this`. `var $this` is a conventional name for a jQuery context, but that's all a matter of preference, of course.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var allSelect = $('select');

     $.each(allSelect,function(k,v){

        var thIs = $(this);
    var name = thIs.attr('name');

        if(name == 'colour')
        {
      // Do what you want to do with colour select here eg:-
    thIs.prepend('<option value="1">White</option>
                 <option value="2">Black</option>
                 <option value="3">Gray</option>');
    } else if(name == 'size'){
      // Do what you want to do with size select here
    } else if(name == 'flavour'){
      // Do what you want to do with flavour select here
    }
       return false;
   });

});
```